# async/await function is not working as descirbed in MDN web docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I know this questions gets asked a lot and I have looked at many similar ones but haven't been able to solve it. But I wrote my code exactly as described in MDN webdocs for async/await but it's not working as expected. Basically I am trying to seed my mongo database for my express.js application.

```
const Activity = require('./Models/activity');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const faker = require('faker');


function dropDB() {

//Check if collections exist. Drop if they do.
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/auth_demo", { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', (err, res) => {


    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
        // console.log(names); // [{ name: 'dbname.myCollection' }]
        if (names.length > 1) {
            console.log("db connect");
            db.dropCollection('users', (err, res) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else {
                    console.log("DB dropped sucessfully");
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log("no collections to drop");
        }
    });
})
}


function createUsers() {
    var usersAdded  = new Array();

    return new Promise(resolve => {
    for (let i = 0; i<20; i++) {
       User.register( new User( 
            {
                username: faker.internet.userName(),
                name: faker.name.firstName() + " " + faker.name.lastName(),
                zipcode: faker.address.zipCode(),
                friends: []
            }
        ), faker.internet.password(), (err, user) => {

            if (err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                usersAdded.push(user);
            }
        }
        )
    };

    resolve(usersAdded);
});

}

async function main() {
    dropDB();
    let x = await createUsers();
    return x;
}

const returnedVal = main();

returnedVal.then((x) => console.log(x.length));

// module.exports = main;
```

This is always what prints to the console:
0,
db connect,
DB dropped sucessfully,

As you can see the `console.log()` in main() runs before createUsers() has finished running. So the users array is still empty even though it should have 20 users.

Comment: You can't just label a function `async` and then use `await` on it and expect it to work.  That's NOT how it works.  You have to make ALL your asynchronous operations use promise-based control flow so that your `async` function returns a promise that resolves/rejects when all the underlying asynchronous operations are complete.  FYI, you have to remove ALL your plain callback asynchronous functions by converting them to promise-based APIs.  Since your database has a promise interface, you should switch to using that everywhere.  Get rid of all code using plain asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: @jfriend00 Right, so I am not saying I disagree but I am just confused because this code snippet from MDN webdocs says that it should work this way. What's the difference between this snippet and my code. Is it just the database interface?

`async function makeResult(items) {
  let newArr = [];
  for(let i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    newArr.push('word_'+i);
  }
  return newArr;
}

async function getResult() {
  let result = await makeResult(items); // Blocked on this line
  useThatResult(result); // Will not be executed before makeResult() is done
}
`

Comment: well that example has no asynchronous code in it which doesn't make it very useful to learn from.

Comment: A good way to explain it is that all async functions return a`Promise` object which wraps the returning value. It doesn't matter if you don't have asynchronous operations going on in you function body. If you declare it as async, it will return a `Promise` and the way to get the value out of it is by using `await` before you invoke it. When there is no value being returned, `Promise` will wrap `undefined`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have edited the question with my new approach with Promises to the best of my ability, but I am still getting the same outcome. Can you please take antother look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong still?